# Derby INSERT SELECT null pointer exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I'm writing a Java application that's working with Apache Derby via JDBC. I'm having problems with the code in the following snippet:

```
byte md5[] = md5sum(file);

PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO input_files (job_ID, hash) SELECT job_id, ? FROM job WHERE job_name = ?");
s.setBytes(1, md5);
s.setString(2, jobName);
s.executeUpdate();
s.close();
```

This inserts into the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE input_files
(
    hash char(16) for bit data,
    job_id integer REFERENCES job,
    PRIMARY KEY(job_id, hash)
);

CREATE TABLE job
(
    job_id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY,
    job_name character varying(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    #other fields
);
```

The idea is that there is an internal integer `job_id` which is used internally by the database, but we want to reference it as much as possible with the human-readable String `job_name`

This consistently throws the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(UnknownSource)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at [line 3 of snippet above]
```

As you can see, this is thrown from the line where the prepared statement is created - it doesn't get as far as executing it. What am I doing wrong? The exact same prepared statement works fine with PostgreSQL.

[edit]
Derby.log:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
2010-08-18 08:47:08.779 GMT:
 Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.6.1.0 - (938214): instance a816c00e-012a-8461-611c-0000046700d0 
on database directory /path/to/myDatabase   with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d6f0472

Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
2010-08-18 08:47:12.067 GMT Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main] (XID = 316), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = myDatabase), (DRDAID = null), Cleanup action starting
2010-08-18 08:47:12.067 GMT Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main] (XID = 316), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = myDatabase), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: INSERT INTO input_files (job_id, hash) SELECT job_id, ? FROM job WHERE job_name = ?
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.BitTypeCompiler.storable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.checkStorableExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at [line 3 of snippet]
Cleanup action completed

2010-08-18 08:47:12.084 GMT:
Shutting down instance a816c00e-012a-8461-611c-0000046700d0 with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d6f0472 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

and unrolled exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at [line 3 of snippet above]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.BitTypeCompiler.storable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.checkStorableExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
SQLState: XJ001
Error code: 0
Message: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': java.lang.NullPointerException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at [line 3 of snippet above]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.BitTypeCompiler.storable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.checkStorableExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
Cause:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.BitTypeCompiler.storable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.checkStorableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.checkStorableExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at [line 3 of snippet above]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A null pointer exception in this context - especially if the same JDBC code works with another DBMS - looks like you've hit a bug in the Derby JDBC driver.  Even if you'd made a mistake and passed erroneous data or a null pointer, the driver should be detecting that and reporting an error, not crashing.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a bug in Derby. You can probably get more information (that is, a more complete stack trace), by unwinding the exception chain: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Also, have a look in derby.log for more information.

Comment: For the record, apparently this was a known bug, and has been fixed in the Derby source. The work around is to add a cast around the parameter - i.e. `INSERT INTO input_files (job_ID, hash) SELECT job_id, CAST(? as CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA) FROM job WHERE job_name = ?`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you won't be able to jam the literal hash code directly into the select column list, because Derby doesn't understand that you want to put a literal value there, rather than a column name.

A reasonable workaround might be to re-code your application to perform the INSERT statement from inside a loop which is reading the values from the SELECT. Something along the lines of:

```
updateStatement = prepareStatement("insert into input_files (job_id, hash) values (?,?)")
ResultSet rs = executeQuery("select job_id from job where job_name = ?")
while (rs.next())
   updateStatement.setString(1, rs.getString(1))
   updateStatement.setBytes(2, md5sum)
   updateStatement.executeUpdate()
```

Comment: As a workaround, I think this is what we'll end up doing. We actually do similar queries in a few places, so if we cache the value of job_id we may actually end up improving our database performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO input_files (job_ID, hash) SELECT job_id, ? FROM job WHERE job_name = ?");
```

"job_ID" vs "job_id" match the case and see if that corrects the problem.

Comment: No joy. I thought SQL was case-insensitive, anyway.

Comment: @Scott: SQL is case-insensitive unless you are using delimited identifiers (double quotes in the standard, square brackets in MS SQL Server, back ticks in MySQL, etc).